# how to read and verify a text file exists or not in python in while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to verify if a file exists or not in the current directory. At the same time, read if the file exists. The below is my code

```
    import os.path
def readdata():
    isFileExist = False
    while isFileExist == False:
        userIN = str(input("Please Enter a file name, followed by .txt: "))
    isExist = os.path.exists(userIN)
        if isFileExistExist == False:
            print(f"Checking... {userIN} DOES NOT exist in the current directory. Please retry.")
        else:
            print(f"Checking... {userIN} exist in the current directory.")
print(f"\n      The file < {userIN} > includes the following data:")
IN = open(userIN,"r")
std1N = IN.readline()
std1M = IN.readline()
std2N = IN.readline()
std2M = IN.readline()
std3N = IN.readline()
std3M = IN.readline()
IN.close()
print(f"      Student Name: {std1N.strip()}")
print(f"      Performance: {std1M.strip()} out of 100")
print(f"      Student Name: {std2N.strip()}")
print(f"      Performance: {std2M.strip()} out of 100")
print(f"      Student Name: {std3N.strip()}")
print(f"      Performance: {std3M.strip()} out of 100")
print(f"      The average exam score of the 3.0 students in the file < {userIN} > is {(eval(s1M.strip())+eval(s2M.strip())+eval(s3M.strip()))/3:.2f}.")

def main():
    readdata()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How to use main to transfer file name to the function readdata()? And then verify if it exists in the current file directory and read the file. As well as, getting the average 3 student's average in that file. I want to transfer the filename from main to readdata() function. How can I achieve that? Thank you for your time and consideration

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of methods to check it.

1. try except

```
try:
    file = open(file_name)
except FileNotFoundError:
    # do something when file not exist
```

2. `pathlib.Path` object has `exists` method.
3. `os.path.isfile` method

To read data from file use:

```
with open(file_name) as f:
    for line in f:
        # do something with current line
# context manager close file automaticly
```

or

```py
with open(file_name) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    # do something with current line
```

Second way is worse then first because:

- first one uses generator
- second one uses creates and use list (slower and use more memory)

But in your case you need to read 2 lines per iteration so you can use `readline` method 2 times per iteration and `break` it when readline return `None`.
e.g

```py
with open(file_name) as f:
    current_name = f.readline()
    current_performance = f.readline()
    while current_name is not None:
        # do something
        current_name = f.readline()
        current_performance = f.readline()
```

You can also extend condition with a `and current_performance is not None` to be sure that u have both values.

Comment: First , thank you very much for your contribution. But how do I check the file exists or not in the main and pass the value to readdata() function?